google_project_iam_audit_config to disable inherited auditing config?
I have audit config set at folder/org/etc.
I want to override the audit object access config for a specific project.
How do I do this with terraform? The only resource I see is "google_project_iam_audit_config" but that only adds config and all its fields are required.
How do I use google_project_iam_audit_config to disable an inherited audit logging config?
